# AlertDialog negative button is not handled

Tags: android

I have an alert dialog with 2 buttons, positive an negative.
Positive button's handler works as it should be, but negative button click doesn't invoke its handler.
Doee anybody know what's wrong here? Thank you.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case DOWNLOAD_DIALOG_ID:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle(R.string.download_videos_title_msg)
                .setMessage(R.string.download_videos_main_msg)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.download_videos_download_btn, 
                    _downloadVideoContent)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.download_videos_ask_later_btn, 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                        {
                            Editor prefEditor = PreferenceManager.
                                getDefaultSharedPreferences(_context).edit();
                            prefEditor.putBoolean(DOWNLOAD_DECLINED_FLAG, true);
                            prefEditor.commit();
                        }
                })
                //.setNegativeButton(R.string.download_videos_ask_later_btn, 
                //  _cancelDialogListener)
                .create();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, 
break point was set at "Editor prefEditor = PreferenceManager." line, because line breaks eclipse didn't stop at that line. Break point at next line worked.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to dismiss or cancel dialog as well.